# error in return codes used in batch (when DLL not present)

Tags: c#, batch-file, dll, return-value

I am having a strange error and I don't know what could be causing it
I have a very simple console application  with a try-catch

```
static int Main()
{
    int returncode = 0;
    try
    {
        //some processing
    }
    catch
    {
        returncode = 1;
    }
    return returncode;
}
```

and a batch file

```
echo off
theprogram.exe
if errorlevel 1 goto Error
if errorlevel 0 goto Sucesss
echo I dont know what happened
echo %errorlevel%
goto :EOF

:Error
echo There was an error
goto :EOF

:Sucess
echo Completed Succesfully
goto :EOF
```

When I execute the batch file in a success condition it goes well.
But when I execute it in a failure condition, even though the return value is 1
I got sometimes 255 and sometime -532462766...

I am at lost why... (I am not used to use batch files)

EDIT:
I did more experimentation. The code uses a DLL. If that DLL is not present, the above situation happens. 
I was guessing that when the DLL is not present it will throw an exception that will be caught by the catch therefore giving a return code of 1 but it seems that does not happen

Something even stranger is that if I throw a "DLLNotFoundException" on purpose, it works well

```
try
{
    throw new DllNotFoundException();
}
catch
{
    returncode = 1;
}
```

but not when the actual DLL is not present

Answer (score 1):

Here's your (*.bat*) code slightly modified (*code.bat*):

```bat
@echo off

call inner.bat %~1

echo ERRORLEVEL: %ERRORLEVEL%

if "%ERRORLEVEL%" equ "0" (
    goto :success
)


:error
    echo There was an error
    goto :eof

:success
    echo Completed Succesfully
    goto :eof
```

*inner.bat*:

```bat
if "%~1" neq "" (
    echo Inner script: exiting with %~1
    exit /b %~1
) else (
    echo Inner script: exiting with 0
    exit /b 0
)
```

**Notes**:

- *inner.bat* - is a replacement for *theprogram.exe*:

  - Returns whatever value it receives as the 1<sup>st</sup> argument (equivalent for the `return` statement which sets the *ExitCode* for a process), 0 if none provided. Check [[SS64]: Command Line arguments (Parameters)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) for more details about arguments, and also [[SS64]: IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- *code.bat*:

  - Calls *inner.bat* with its 1<sup>st</sup> argument (I did this to parametrize the whole thing, so if a different behavior is needed, just pass a different value for the argument instead of modifying the code)
  - Changed the way of checking whether the inner process ended with error: instead of `if ERRORLEVEL value` do `if %ERRORLEVEL equ 0` (although some might argue that this is incorrect, and it's true in some cases it will yield unexpected results). More details, again on [[SS64]: %Errorlevel%](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)
  - This way, 0 means success, and everything else (positive or negative values) means error
  - The `:error` label (the label line **only**, not also the 2 lines after it) is no longer necessary, but I left it there
  - Also did some code and output formatting

**Output**:

> ```
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048860316>code.bat -23456
> Inner script: exiting with -23456
> ERRORLEVEL: -23456
> There was an error
>
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048860316>code.bat
> Inner script: exiting with 0
> ERRORLEVEL: 0
> Completed Succesfully
>
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048860316>code.bat 12
> Inner script: exiting with 12
> ERRORLEVEL: 12
> There was an error
>
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048860316>code.bat 0
> Inner script: exiting with 0
> ERRORLEVEL: 0
> Completed Succesfully
> ```

- Now, whatever the *C#* program's *ExitCode* (!= 0 for error cases) would be, it will be correctly handled by the *.bat*
- There might be some bad error handling in *C#*, which would make the process exit with a wrong *ExitCode*, but there's nothing that the *.bat* could do in that case